# Replace all columns in dataframe from index 1 onwards using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace columns in dataframe after the first column based on the first column. Suppose we have:

```
df = {'Z':  ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0'],
        'A': ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
        'B': ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
        'C': ['1', '0', '0', '0', '`1']}

df = pd.DataFrame (df, columns = ['Z','A','B','C'])

df
```

I want to replace the columns with `1 IF column = Z ELSE 0` .

The desired outcome is the following:

```
df2 = {'Z':  ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0'],
        'A': ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1'],
        'B': ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1'],
        'C': ['1', '1', '0', '0', '`0']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame (df2, columns = ['Z','A','B','C'])

df2
```

The problem is that I have 60 columns (A,B,C,D,.....) and I want to be able to do them at the same time.

Comment: What does `1 if z = COLUMN ELSE 0.` means?

Comment: IF column = Z THEN 1 ELSE 0

Comment: What is column?

Comment: IF column A = column Z THEN 1 ELSE 0

But I need it for all columns in one go as I have 60. The above was just to provide context

Comment: Are all the columns numbers?

Comment: the columns output should be numbers

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
# Z column
z = df.iloc[:, 0].values

# rest of columns
rest = df.iloc[:, 1:].values

# do comparison and set values
df.iloc[:, 1:] = (z[:, None] == rest).astype(int)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Z  A  B  C
0  1  1  0  1
1  0  0  1  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  1  0
```

If you need a new DataFrame, do the following:

```
z = df.iloc[:, 0].values
rest = df.iloc[:, 1:].values

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=(z[:, None] == rest).astype(int), columns=df.columns[1:], index=df['Z']).reset_index()
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
   Z  A  B  C
0  1  1  0  1
1  0  0  1  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dani Masejo! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Majeso - suppose some of the values in A, B or C included Nan and I wanted them to stay as Nan - what would I need to add to the code for this?

Comment: @JoeSmart Who has nan values z, or the rest of the columns?

Comment: Z has no NaN. A,B,C may have some NaN. If they do have NaN I want them to remain as they do. The method is used above converts NaN to 0

Comment: @JoeSmart Just set them back to nan

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: try `df2.where(pd.isna(df), np.nan)` have to import numpy

Comment: The 0's remain as 0's when they should be NaN

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) along `axis=0` to compare the column `Z` with rest of the columns then `join` the resulting dataframe with the column `Z` and `mask` the `NaN` values:

```
df[['Z']].join(df.drop('Z', 1).eq(df['Z'], axis=0).astype(int)).mask(df.isna())
```

---

```
   Z  A  B  C
0  1  1  0  1
1  0  0  1  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an easy way to do that by checking for equality and converting to integer.

```
z = df["Z"]
others = [c for c in df.columns if c != "Z"] # all columns but 'Z'

df[others] = df[others].transform(lambda x : x.eq(z).astype(int))
```

outputs :

```
   Z  A  B  C
0  1  1  0  1
1  0  0  1  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  1  0
```

Note that there is a way to keep the `NA`'s, you must use pandas datatypes though, see [nullable data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) and [text data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-types).